# Sort by Multiplying

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic

You should write a program or function that given a list of positive integers multiplies each element with the smallest positive integer possible to create a strictly increasing list.

For example if the input is

```
5 4 12 1 3
```

the multiplications will be

```
5*1=5 4*2=8 12*1=12 1*13=13 3*5=15
```

and the output will be the increasing list

```
5 8 12 13 15
```

### Input

- A list of positive integers containing at least 1 element

### Output

- A list of positive integers

### Examples

```
9 => 9
1 2 => 1 2
2 1 => 2 3
7 3 => 7 9
1 1 1 1 => 1 2 3 4
5 4 12 1 3 => 5 8 12 13 15
3 3 3 8 16 => 3 6 9 16 32
6 5 4 3 2 1 => 6 10 12 15 16 17
9 4 6 6 5 78 12 88 => 9 12 18 24 25 78 84 88
8 9 41 5 12 3 5 6 => 8 9 41 45 48 51 55 60
15 8 12 47 22 15 4 66 72 15 3 4 => 15 16 24 47 66 75 76 132 144 150 153 156
```

This is code golf so the shortest program or function wins.

*Fun fact: the last element of the output for the input `N, N-1, ... ,1` seems to be the `(N+1)th` element of the sequence [A007952](http://oeis.org/A007952). If you find a proof, you are welcomed to include it in your golf answer or post it as a comment.*

Comment: has anyone made ground on that proof yet?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
:‘×µ\
```

First Jelly answer <s>before @Dennis wakes up and beats me.</s> [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=OuKAmMOXwrVc&input=&args=WzMsIDMsIDMsIDgsIDE2XQ)

#### Explanation

```
:          Integer division, m//n
 ‘         Increment, (m//n+1)
  ×        Multiply, (m//n+1)*n
   µ       Turn the previous links into a new monadic chain
    \      Accumulate on the array
```

Thanks to @Dennis for -1 byte.

Comment: ``:‘×µ\`` saves a byte.

Comment: @Dennis Oh shit he woke up

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), 28

**Edit** As suggested by @Patrick Roberts, `p` can be a uninitialized parameter. Same byte count but avoid using a global variable

```js
(a,p)=>a.map(n=>p=n*-~(p/n))
```

**TEST**

```js
f=(a,p)=>a.map(n=>p=n*-~(p/n))

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

;[
[[9], [ 9]],
[[1, 2], [ 1, 2]],
[[2, 1], [ 2, 3]],
[[7, 3], [ 7, 9]],
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [ 1, 2, 3, 4]],
[[5, 4, 12, 1, 3], [ 5, 8, 12, 13, 15]],
[[3, 3, 3, 8, 16], [ 3, 6, 9, 16, 32]],
[[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [ 6, 10, 12, 15, 16, 17]],
[[9, 4, 6, 6, 5, 78, 12, 88], [ 9, 12, 18, 24, 25, 78, 84, 88]],
[[8, 9, 41, 5, 12, 3, 5, 6], [ 8, 9, 41, 45, 48, 51, 55, 60]],
[[15, 8, 12, 47, 22, 15, 4, 66, 72, 15, 3, 4], [ 15, 16, 24, 47, 66, 75, 76, 132, 144, 150, 153, 156]]
].forEach(t=>{
  var i=t[0],k=t[1],r=f(i),ok=(k+'')==(r+'')
  console.log(i + ' => ' + r + (ok?' OK':'FAIL expecting '+x))
})
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: I think you can save a few bytes by using modulo, just like I did in [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71553/38392).

Comment: Can't you skip the p=0?  You need it to run it multiple on multiple lists but the question is just for a single list

Comment: @CharlieWynn if you don't initialize a variable you get the error for undefined variable. If by chance the variable already exists (that could easily happen in the environment of a web page), it could have any wrong value.

Comment: @edc65 sure enough, p is already defined on this page!

Comment: A neat way to do this using ES7 generator comprehensions is [`(a,p)=>[for(n of a)p=n*-~(p/n)]`](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=true&code=let%20o%3D(a%2Cp)%3D%3E%5Bfor(n%20of%20a)p%3Dn*-~(p%2Fn)%5D%3Balert(o(%5B5%2C4%2C12%2C1%2C3%5D)))

Comment: @PatrickRoberts can be neat but is longer. The `p` as a parameter is a nice idea, I'm using it

Comment: @edc65 glad you liked my parameter format. Just pointing out that by "neat" I did not mean shorter.

Comment: @edc65 I hate to make you revert to a global variable, but you can save 3 bytes by changing your function to `a=>a.map(n=>p+=n-p%n,p=0)` as @aross suggested.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thinking again, I could still avoid globals: `f=a=>a.map(n=>a+=n-a%n,a=0)`. But it's not my algorithm (silly me) so I'll keep mine as is and upvote aross

Comment: @edc65 if you want to keep your algorithm and save **4 bytes**, then use `a=>a.map(n=>a=n*-~(a/n))`!

Comment: @PatrickRoberts sorry for the late answer ... that fails for an array with just 1 element

Comment: Can you `a=>a.map(p=n=>p=n*-~(p/n))` instead?

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, <strike>67</strike> 64 bytes

First try at code-golfing, so tips are appreciated.

```
def m(l):
 for x in range(1,len(l)):l[x]*=l[x-1]/l[x]+1
 print l
```

Comment: Hi, I think you're counting the line returns as 2 bytes each (using Windows?), but on this site you count each line return as a single byte.  So your score is actually 65 bytes. (You can copy and paste your code into https://mothereff.in/byte-counter if you're not sure.) Also, you can do `print l` instead of `return l` to save another byte. Nice job!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the line returns. That explains why I've always got different byte counts. And I didn't even consider, that printing is sufficient and it doesn't have to return the list.

Comment: No problem! BTW, since you mentioned that "tips are appreciated", you might be interested in browsing through http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python . Enjoy!

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, <s>55</s> <s>46</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

Uses ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
for(;$a=$argv[++$i];)echo$l+=$a-$l%$a,~ß;
```

Run like this (`-d` added for aesthetics only):

```
php -d error_reporting=30709 -r 'for(;$a=$argv[++$i];)echo$l+=$a-$l%$a,~ß;' 10 10 8
```

- Saved 1 byte thx to Ismael Miguel.
- Saved 8 bytes by using modulo instead of floor
- Saved 4 bytes thx to Ismael Miguel (for instead of foreach)
- Saved a byte by using `~ß` to yield a space.

Comment: I think that you can replace `$a+0` with `+$a`. Also, you can assume that the input will never have a `0`, so, you can replace your `$a+0&&print` with simply `+$a&print`. In fact, you could even do `$a&print`, since in PHP `"0" == 0 == 0.0 == false`. But it may not be needed if you just use an `echo`, I think.

Comment: Binary `and` won't work (as opposed to logical), nor will echo work in this way. Since I'm taking input from CLI, the first argument is `-`, which I wanna catch instead of printing a zero. Try `php -r 'print_r($argv);' foo`. Saved 1 byte with your first suggestion though, thx.

Comment: How about `for(;$a=$argv[++$i];)echo$l+=$a-$l%$a,' ';`? It is 42 bytes long and skips the first element.

Comment: Nice one, thx @IsmaelMiguel

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to be really kinky, you can replace the space with `a^A`, but that would spill too many warnings (warnings are ignorable). It won't change the bytecount in any way, but surelly looks different.

Comment: I know warnings are ignorable, hence I don't initiate `$l`. But how would I print a linebreak in less than 3 characters exactly? Without resorting to non-standard constants of course

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35509/discussion-between-aross-and-ismael-miguel).

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. Your solution is probably the best for this problem and I don't want to steal it. +1

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell (<del>30</del> <del>28</del> 25 bytes)

```
scanl1(\x y->y*div x y+y)
```

#### Expanded version

```
f :: Integral n => [n] -> [n]
f xs = scanl1 increaseOnDemand xs
 where
   increaseOnDemand :: Integral n => n -> n -> n
   increaseOnDemand acc next = next * (1 + acc `div` next)
```

#### Explanation

`scanl1` enables you to fold a list and accumulate all intermediate values into another list. It's a specialization of `scanl`, which has the following type:

```
scanl  :: (acc  -> elem -> acc)  -> acc -> [elem] -> [acc]
scanl1 :: (elem -> elem -> elem) ->        [elem] -> [elem]

scanl1 f (x:xs) = scanl f x xs
```

Therefore, all we need is a suitable function that takes two the last element of our list (`acc` in the expanded version) and the one we wish to process (`next` in the expanded version) and return a suitable number.

We can easily derive this number by dividing the accumulator through the next one and flooring the result. `div` takes care of that. Afterwards, we simply have to add `1` to ensure that the list is actually increasing (and that we don't end up with `0`).

Comment: No need to give your function a name. You can also replace the `( ... )` with `$ ...` and I think you've counted a final newline which can be omitted: `scanl1$\x y->y*div x y+y`, 24 bytes.

Comment: @nimi: Really? Expressions count? That being said, I don't save any bytes with `(...)` vs `$`, since `$\ ` gets parsed as operator and I would need a single space after `$`.

Comment: unnamed function are allowed by default an `scanl1(...)` is an unnamed function. Regarding `$`vs. `()`: you're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

## C++, <del>63</del> <del>60</del> 57 bytes

```
void s(int*f,int*e){for(int c=*f;++f!=e;c=*f+=c/ *f**f);}
```

Works inplace given a range `[first, last)`. Originally written as template variant, but that was longer:

```
template<class T>void s(T f,T e){for(auto c=*f;++f!=e;c=*f+=c/ *f**f);}
```

#### Extended version

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
void sort(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last){
    auto previous = *first;

    for(++first; first != last; ++first){
        auto & current = *first;
        current += current * (current / previous);
        previous = current;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, <del>36</del> 32 bytes

```
 #2(Floor[#1/#2]+1)&~FoldList~#&
```

### Test

```
#2(Floor[#1/#2]+1)&~FoldList~#& /@ {{5, 4, 12, 1, 3}, 
   {15, 8, 12, 47, 22, 15, 4, 66, 72, 15, 3, 4}}
(* {{5, 8, 12, 13, 15}, {15, 16, 24, 47, 66, 75, 76, 132, 144, 
  150, 153, 156}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 12 bytes

```
{≤.;?%0∧}ᵐ<₁
```

Weird enough trying to multiply each variable by a number will start at trying to multiply by 2 and not 0 or 1. This seems to work though and beats both other Brachylog implementations

## Explanation

```
{       }ᵐ          --  Map each number
 ≤.                 --      to a number greater or equal to the original
  .;?%0             --      and a multiple of the original
       ∧            --      no more constraints
          <₁        --  so that the list is strictly increasing
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/pR5xI9a3tVg0cdy2sfbp1g86ip8f//aENTBQsFQyMFE3MFIyMFIM9EwcxMwRzMNFYwif0fBQA)

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 13 bytes

```
q~{\_p1$/)*}*
```

Input as a CJam-style list. Output is linefeed separated.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%7B%5C_p1%24%2F)*%7D*&input=%5B15%208%2012%2047%2022%2015%204%2066%2072%2015%203%204%5D)

#### Explanation

```
q~    e# Read and evaluate input.
{     e# Fold this block over the list (i.e. "foreach except first")...
  \   e#   Swap with previous value.
  _p  e#   Duplicate and print previous value.
  1$  e#   Copy current value.
  /   e#   Integer division.
  )*  e#   Increment and multiply current value by the result.
}*
```

The final value is left on the stack and printed automatically at the end.

Answer (score 3):

### Python (3.5), <s>63</s> 62 bytes

```
def f(a):
 r=[0]
 for i in a:r+=i*(r[-1]//i+1),
 return r[1:]
```

### Test

```
>>> print('\n'.join([str(i)+' => '+str(f(i)) for i in [[9],[1,2],[2,1],[7,3],[1,1,1,1],[5,4,12,1,3],[3,3,3,8,16],[6,5,4,3,2,1],[9,4,6,6,5,78,12,88],[8,9,41,5,12,3,5,6],[15,8,12,47,22,15,4,66,72,15,3,4]]]))
[9] => [9]
[1, 2] => [1, 2]
[2, 1] => [2, 3]
[7, 3] => [7, 9]
[1, 1, 1, 1] => [1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 4, 12, 1, 3] => [5, 8, 12, 13, 15]
[3, 3, 3, 8, 16] => [3, 6, 9, 16, 32]
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] => [6, 10, 12, 15, 16, 17]
[9, 4, 6, 6, 5, 78, 12, 88] => [9, 12, 18, 24, 25, 78, 84, 88]
[8, 9, 41, 5, 12, 3, 5, 6] => [8, 9, 41, 45, 48, 51, 55, 60]
[15, 8, 12, 47, 22, 15, 4, 66, 72, 15, 3, 4] => [15, 16, 24, 47, 66, 75, 76, 132, 144, 150, 153, 156]
```

### Previous solution

some recursive solutions but larger

```
(68 bytes) f=lambda a,i=0:[i,*f(a[1:],a[0]*(i//a[0]+1))][i==0:]if a!=[]else[i]
(64 bytes) f=lambda a,i=0:a>[]and[i,*f(a[1:],a[0]*(i//a[0]+1))][i<1:]or[i]
```

Comment: Also instead of `r+=[…]`, you can use `r+=…,`

Comment: @Cyoce i make changes but when i defined `r=[0]` in default parameter `r` become nonlocal

Comment: you're right, I forgot how Python handled default params. The other tip should work though

Comment: @Cyoce yes it works thanks for tips

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 17 + 3 = 20 bytes

```
$p=$_*=$==1+$p/$_
```

Requires `-p` and `-l` flags:

```
$ perl -ple'$p=$_*=$==1+$p/$_' <<< $'15\n8\n12\n47\n22\n15\n4\n66\n72\n15\n3\n4'
15
16
24
47
66
75
76
132
144
150
153
156
```

Explanation:

```
# '-p' reads each line into $_ and auto print
# '-l' chomp off newline on input and also inserts a new line when printing
# When assigning a number to `$=` it will automatic be truncated to an integer
# * Added newlines for each assignment 
$p=
  $_*=
    $==
      1+$p/$_
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 37 bytes

```c
o(int*_){for(;*++_;)*_*=_[~0]/ *_+1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDLasMwEDw3X2EMBUneUst6WEGkxfmCHHJLgykuKTnULml6Ms6vuyspbu24GIR3dmZ3dqqH96rq@4Yc6zMraXtoTsSyJCktZSVblbtLun@MWJlw2/UbzyoC6/OExYHEbUwtKywd6vs3iIEVSULtAHUvNZK6xTbowb1r2g7tKIqwvSEFtY17Bvzy9IsP0Oo5QGuEvs9fJPZzP16PNaHt4m5L3IbdnrZLSDsYF9SO2xyyMSGUU0oGfEzJQMwoucfgr/xvUfhulgmQM6pCjLutk6EKjEcFcDWTCHAfEvRYIkCjE8TE/CoNbo2Am@s08NSvUU7H85luiSoNTp17P8ZMA3ZaA5mEzDOMDIzpEIO2JMcZ3CWgYOL62pToz4BCFvbTeZ7XPGQOmbeLtjTk/jeECiMq3oKWkOs4aAxPw0y4xKAV3qtcqDrs6Pof)

Comment: [38 bytes, recursive approach](https://tio.run/##bVDLasMwEDw3XxEMBUneUst6WKlJg/MFOeSWBlFcUnKoXdL0ZJxfd1dS3NpxMQjv7Mzu7JQP72XZdTU5VmdmacPi2K6YZUu7uyT7x5jZmENNLH2yedttPK2gzaE@kc8TFgcSNRHNWZHTvr5/gwhYEcc076H2pUJSO9sGPbh3TZu@PZ/Psb0hBc1r9/T45fkX76HlKkBrhL7PXyTycz9ejxWhzexuS9yG3Z42C0haGBY0H7Y5pENCKMeUFPiQkoKYUDKPwV/536Lw3SwTICdUhRh3W0dDFRiPCuBqIhHgPiTooUSARieIielVGtwaATfXaeCJX6OcjmcT3QJVGpw6836MGQfstAZSCalnGBkY4yEGbUmOM7hLQMHI9bUp0Z8BhSzsJ9M8r3nIDFJvF21pyPxvCBUGVLwFLSHXcdAYnoaZcIlBK7xXuVB12NF2Pw).

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, <s>43</s> <s>40</s> 37 bytes

```
Prompt A
For(I,1,dim(ʟA
ʟA(I)(1+int(Ans/ʟA(I→ʟA(I
End
ʟA
```

-6 bytes thanks to [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush).

Comment: [37 bytes](https://pastebin.com/ELgSgnQM) with a fresh calculator or Ans = 0

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 54 bytes

```
:_{h_.|[L:T],LhH,(T_,IH;0:$Ie*H=:T>I),Lb:I:1&:[I]rc.}.
```

#### Explanation

```
:_{...}.                § Call sub-predicate 1 with [Input, []] as input. Unify its output
                        § with the output of the main predicate


§ Sub-predicate 1

h_.                     § If the first element of the input is an empty list, unify the
                        § output with the empty list
|                       § Else
[L:T],LhH,              § Input = [L,T], first element of L is H
    (T_,IH              §     If T is the empty list, I = H
    ;                   §     Else
    0:$Ie*H=:T>I),      §     Enumerate integers between 0 and +inf, stop and unify the
                        §     enumerated integer with I only if I*H > T
Lb:I:1&                 § Call sub-predicate 1 with input [L minus its first element, I]
:[I]rc.                 § Unify the output of the sub-predicate with
                        § [I|Output of the recursive call]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 11

```
t.u*Yh/NYQ0
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=t.u%2AYh%2FNYQ0&input=%5B5%2C%204%2C%2012%2C%201%2C%203%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B9%5D%0A%5B1%2C%202%5D%0A%5B2%2C%201%5D%0A%5B7%2C%203%5D%0A%5B1%2C%201%2C%201%2C%201%5D%0A%5B5%2C%204%2C%2012%2C%201%2C%203%5D%0A%5B3%2C%203%2C%203%2C%208%2C%2016%5D%0A%5B6%2C%205%2C%204%2C%203%2C%202%2C%201%5D%0A%5B9%2C%204%2C%206%2C%206%2C%205%2C%2078%2C%2012%2C%2088%5D%0A%5B8%2C%209%2C%2041%2C%205%2C%2012%2C%203%2C%205%2C%206%5D%0A%5B15%2C%208%2C%2012%2C%2047%2C%2022%2C%2015%2C%204%2C%2066%2C%2072%2C%2015%2C%203%2C%204%5D&debug=0)

Does a cumulative reduce, a reduce that returns all intermediate values, starting with `0`. Since the input is guaranteed to contain only positive integers, this is ok. In each step, we take the old value, divide it by the new value and add `1`, then we multiply by the new value.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 79 bytes

```c
p;main(x,v)char**v;{for(;*++v;printf("%d ",p=((x+p-1)/x+!(p%x))*x))x=atoi(*v);}
```

### Ungolfed

```
p; /* previous value */

main(x,v) char**v;
{
    /* While arguments, print out x such that x[i] > x[i-1] */
    for(;*++v; printf("%d ", p = ((x+p-1)/x + !(p%x)) * x))
        x = atoi(*v);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `p=p/x*x+x` work?

Comment: @Neil Yeah, that would work. Definitely overthought this one :)

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, 26 bytes

```
$args[0]|%{($l+=$_-$l%$_)}
```

Takes input as an explicit array, e.g., `> .\sort-by-multiplying.ps1 @(6,5,4,3,2,1)` via `$args[0]`.

We then for-loop over that with `|%{...}` and each iteration perform *magic*. Nah, just kidding, we use the same modulo trick as other answers (props to @aross because I spotted it [there](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71553/42963) first).

The encapsulating parens `(...)` ensure that the result of the math operation is placed on the pipeline, and thus output. If we left those off, nothing would be output since the `$l` variable is garbage-collected after execution finishes.

#### Example

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\sort-by-multiplying.ps1 @(8,9,1,5,4)
8
9
10
15
16
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 27 bytes

```julia
!L=(x=0;L.|>i->x=(x÷i+1)i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU9LboMwFNz7FBMWEagU4S@mFey6qJRLkIZIrhBFhEoseq8eoAejz4@0tmSP38zzzHv/HEIn1207nJp0bcrnU/HVhsd2pdfPd3iQWci268eMgDBi7rvLEMb@lmYCtLr8jAa3aQhLkfKVhhxJ0yZZtv8zdfOtL9LXccnD3jNTx6FjOM1hXIYx7dC0mP/oQ4Mzjsd/NnlZp/5t6S9PSHKcM9GPl62OLbWQUBHQJRSdBBW0qKAjrFiw711EdSMsDGRUs8jC80tDWqERNxVcpDQc6oi1Eg6xTePu4iBLbrORl5WoiXWIqor/854DssZDGShmvCFGeCKMJK2MiSzY7V405ONhiaV6KeQ9n6mg2I5sHCqGNAzPxRnIgjSRIyOKpEliaFBLOW0czv0C)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 59 bytes

```rust
|mut l:Vec<u8>|{for i in 1..l.len(){l[i]*=l[i-1]/l[i]+1};l}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc5LCoMwEADQvaeIrrSdWuInplrbW3QjLopECMS02FgEzdnTxH1lYD7wZphx@ijTSzQ8uQyjxRNMobk26zApJMoH664Tva1L/xoRR1wiHMciFsxZ0fD2UNt8wu3ZDUesK6FN5b1HLpWQfhgs5V0HMIdf1vlNDhngBDCkbRT9VReriI0cCuo4pXuagvXYYitTW8gexjlsJ7MCEvuH@4cQKLY2hWxb1eYH)

I am still learning rust, but I am sure there is a better solution using `iter()`. Also I am using `u8` because the examples don't have output value  greater than 512.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 35 bytes

```factor
[ 0 [ tuck /i 1 + * ] accumulate* ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY3NDsFAFIUjsepTnMSO-JkO7eABxMZGrMRiMhkhtKpmFiJ9EptueCeexu2UYu7innPPlzPX-1oqc0jzZ62-mE9nkxF2Oo31HpE0G5z00epY6ROSVBtzTtJtbDD2vIsHehcMkb0Vg19pn9xHh-A_TDkfP0AfrIC_CHcjwILqFDiO_7UO6RK4JBRFhRBVJIqQUUJnTutbxAZwcD-E7xeOOgKETnIymZfdrFm3xaOxRA9LGKt26G7p3xaaWEEqZSO7l0aTK9FbJBN0Sp3n5X4B)

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 25 bytes

```
a->i=0;[i=c*(i\c+1)|c<-a]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY9BCsIwEEWvErpqdAKmaZMUbS9Sg4RCJSASSl0I3sRNQcQzuPMa3saZRgby_7yfH8j9Ff0YDsc4PwbWPC_TIOzbizY0m20Xmn6Vh32_lvzW74R3Kf9-fIyna-6ZaFkcw3lCm9GSsSH3nAPrutrhKaEgKUCSGFAJLkO2ghIkpilQQGNBato0UKrgX65x0UDQWOpYS9QCcokQiUJZmrKC5UppoMA2PaM1mMUqKJ3j6R_znPQH)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 78 bytes

```
n->min(n,i.length)+1,o->join(o,i[n]floor(o[n-1]/i[n]+1))
i=\ans_0
n=2
o=[i[1]]
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bozvnxcqyl)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/z0abv2uhes)

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 9 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
\(×+1⌊÷,)
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgXCjDlysx4oyKw7csKQoKZiBbOV0KZiBbMSAyXQpmIFsyIDFdCmYgWzEgMSAxIDFdCmYgWzUgNCAxMiAxIDNd)

```
\(×+1⌊÷,)
\(      )  # scan by
       ,   # over
      ÷    # divide
     ⌊     # floor
   +1      # increment
  ×        # multiply
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), 8 bytes

```
\(-⊃◿+∶)
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgXCgt4oqD4pe_K-KItikKCmYgWzldCmYgWzEgMl0KZiBbMiAxXQpmIFsxIDEgMSAxXQpmIFs1IDQgMTIgMSAzXQ==)

Given the previous value `x` and the next value `y`, the transformed `y` is the same as `(x+y) - (x+y)%y == (x+y) - x%y`.

```
\(-⊃◿+∶)    input: a vector of positive integers
\(      )    scan by: (input: [x y])
       :       swap [y x]
   ⊃◿+        fork (mod, add) [x%y x+y]
  -            subtract [x+y-x%y]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

Code:

```
R`[=sŽDŠ/ò*
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=UmBbPXPFvUTFoC_Dsio&input=WzIsIDMsIDMsIDIsIDQsIDVd)

Explanation:

```
R            # Reverse input
 `           # Flatten the list
  [          # While loop
   =         # Print the last item
    s        # Swap the last two items
     Ž       # If the stack is empty, break
      D      # Duplicate top of the stack
       Š     # Pop a,b,c and push c,a,b
        /    # Divide a / b
         ò   # Inclusive round up
          *  # Multiply the last two items
```

Uses CP-1252 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 11 bytes

```
Uå@Y*-~(X/Y
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VeVAWSotfihYL1k=&input=WzUgNCAxMiAxIDNd)

#### How it works

```
          // Implicit: U = input array of integers
Uå@       // Cumulative reduce: map each previous value X and current value Y to:
-~(X/Y    //  floor(X/Y+1).
          // Implicit: output last expression
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Minkolang 0.15](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 17 bytes

```
nd1+?.z0c:1+*d$zN
```

[Try it here!](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=nd1%2B%3F%2Edz%24r%3A1%2B*d%24zN&input=15%208%2012%2047%2022%2015%204%2066%2072%2015%203%204)

#### Explanation

```
nd                   Take number from input and duplicate it
  1+                 Add 1
    ?.               Stop if top of stack is 0 (i.e., when n => -1 because input is empty).
      z              Push value from register
       0c            Copy first item on stack
         :           Pop b,a and push a//b
          1+         Add 1
            *        Multiply
             d$z     Duplicate and store in register
                N    Output as number
```

Essentially, the register keeps the latest member of the ascending list and this is divided by the input and incremented to get the multiplier for the next member. The toroidal feature of Minkolang's code field means that it loops horizontally without the need for `()` or `[]` loops.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 21 bytes

```
l~lCℕ₁ᵐ≤ᵛ~+?&;Cz≜×ᵐ<₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P6cux/lRy9RHTY0Pt0541Lnk4dbZddr2atbOVY865xyeDhS0Acr9/x9tqmCiYGikYKhgHPs/CgA)

Uses the sum of input values as [the upper bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2873481/85653) for coefficients C. Pretty slow, times out on TIO for input list lengths beyond 5 or 6 (also depending on the sum of the values). But not as slow as my original version, which requires tiny lists of upto 3 elements, with tiny values, to not time out:

#### 21 bytes

```
l~l.&+^₂⟦₁⊇.;?z/ᵐℕ₁ᵐ∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P6cuR09NO@5RU9Oj@cseNTU@6mrXs7av0n@4dcKjlqlAARCjY/n//9HGOgpAZKijYBT7PwoA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda a:reduce(lambda b,v:b+[b[-1]/v*v+v],a,[0])[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBDoIwEETP@hW9ATJGS6GUJvgjtQdQiE0UCEESvx631WyyO/N2Z6fP8hiHbOvr6/ZsXu29YY2eu/v71sV/32LVbWpac@T2tB7WdLVoYM42MVzbrR9n5pgbmDGVheHIqGfg1EuIQEKRKpCD0ypgAV8KXJKR8DuBX64iLeFZqXxAKYIKhDkxAoKGj/EC4SAvkVHU/5ASZZACubV6v5tmNyzMIaovEfrYJdsX)

`k*x>y` implies `k>y/x`; so the smallest `k` can be is `k=floor(y/x)+1`. Since in Python 2.7, integer division is already taken as `floor`, we want `k=y/x+1`, and `k*x = (y/x+1)*x = y/x*x+x`.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 11 bytes

```
{y*1+_x%y}\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYs7DsMwDEOvwqXoDxlkObJSXSVAtiwZujYoenaXMjiIfCKP6X30vr@@50Oe2@dy/ta@43pbQlCiQKJB6YdiRoUQEilSDrEwJFdke6EzJGmeVfdwEAoJo/JYyIzxrA2Fo1yboQ2rqPf@Bw)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 21 bytes

```
(],[*1+{:@]<.@%[)/@|.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBBSwQxDIXv/oqHIOvq7jhpmzQzuDAgePLkddmTuIgXf4D@9zFNuixlmPblfelLv9fbYXPGYcYGO4yY7dsPeHl/e13vT7vjAz3@zsvpeVjujtun5W9YtzefH18/mHDAGVMcCAn72c62CSUhh5JAoVRDXKnIVyqjXEhfUWEoyMgM4iiz@ZpyYTPE@pEg95uzL8MkDAIaneDmohou8Ub5mmpyjyIVJEZVaIFqmCeziiPV46gGo61CKNZKwQRmyBhIL3GzZ/v1MBHC7igVIqjW0TJZdCo2FltQbqNKf4o@vpmTD1Ac8q291/oP)

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 machine code, 13 bytes

```
99 F7 3E F7 2E 01 06 AD FF CF 75 F4 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVNRb9owEH6Of8UtU1enuIgQGjIYfWlfp01o0iYBD67tgKfgsMR0YVH@@tjZDCp1L1Os@O77vvvOvihit7tdC3E88noLFOYhJf11UT7xAnIGFakmgZA/SKClfobHr5/mj/D5yxwWVa1XiG73xb8ol/IUMlC8IfkkKEpZSxJIJUBJTYLv5hd6B5WyJAohmhLVWFUZCB9CaJ9LLSGn2lgwDNx2w6MpeLh6DXeEvNVGFHup4ENtpS77m3tCasutFlDbai8sWFVbwWsFra@e@mq@iNMV1p/JerGCGbSkjVn7vusYaYcM4@E5HLL4HI5Z4sORE/jHp3cM14jFqPwrQCRh7slYnHokZbicKmFnwwz7IZAyR4wzV59lZyZjyMVIIJrgdnKJ3dHumNeOxmyIVs4zTdnYhwkbOV03Je6mW64NjUhLgrysgPK9LeGdhcllLnVEAmRPtKvQOIkBjgnezMD23cB6PdQEwa5COqfhlYaQIcUXeoWf74W4vQ99nlOs84pT@t/OcKVfOe@t2PCKXi/NtQM6EpCLemk@crHRRoEopZr43q5N49owOGAqS2hfzAfDb2h/mFG6N7VeGyXBud9EVbRoej1s2cHPjS4U0IM746B5SJzpxYHi1Z8OOLloadCpQbI7Hn@LvODr@ni7TUf4wp9phnpV/AE)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes the length of an array of 32-bit integers in RDI and its address in RSI. The starting point is after the first 7 bytes.

In assembly:

```
                            # Here, EAX holds the modified previous number.
r:  cdq                     # Sign-extend it, preparing for the next instruction.
    idiv DWORD PTR [rsi]    # Divide by the current number, putting the quotient in EAX
                            #  and the remainder in EDX.
    imul DWORD PTR [rsi]    # Multiply the quotient by the current number; the net effect
                            #  is to round EAX down to a multiple of the current number.
    add [rsi], eax          # Add EAX to the current number, producing the first multiple
                            #  greater than the modified previous number.
f:  lodsd       # (Start here.) Load the current number into EAX, advancing the pointer.
    dec edi     # Count down from the length.
    jnz r       # Jump if it hasn't reached 0.
    ret         # Return.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
≬ḭ›*r
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiazhuK3igLoqciIsIiIsIlsxNSwgOCwgMTIsIDQ3LCAyMiwgMTUsIDQsIDY2LCA3MiwgMTUsIDMsIDRdIl0=)

Port of Jelly answer.

### How?

```
≬ḭ›*r
≬     # Next three elements as a lambda:
 ḭ    # Floor divide: a/b
  ›   # Increment: a/b+1
   *  # Multiply: (a/b+1)*b
    r # Cumulative reduce the (implicit) input by this lambda
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
æ`/)*]ç
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##JYxRDsJACET/vYlmEsOyZelZmk30R/3Q@NMz1YP0YOtAQzIMD4bPfX09v@/HGPt2u54vff@Nscz9tAgKtUCoDZoki25ChXCVWBHlEONgiJ3iyM30hmDNI@BO6CAWMgJli5hMyIPaUBiNH2ZoaRW1/wE)

**Explanation:**

```python
æ        # Loop over the (implicit) input-list,
         # using 4 characters as inner code-block:
         #  (implicitly push the current value)
 `       #  Duplicate the top two values
         #  (which will push a 0 as first item in the first iteration)
  /      #  Integer-divide those two duplicated values
   )     #  Increase it by 1
    *    #  Multiply the top two values together
     ]   # After the loop: wrap all values on the stack into a list
      ç  # Remove the leading 0 with a falsey filter
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 210 bytes

```
WITH v AS(SELECT TO_NUMBER(COLUMN_VALUE)a,rownum i FROM XMLTABLE(('"'||REPLACE(:1,' ','","')||'"'))),c(p,n)AS(SELECT a,2 FROM v WHERE i=1UNION ALL SELECT a*CEIL((p+.1)/a),n+1 FROM c,v WHERE i=n)SELECT p FROM c;
```

Un-golfed

```
WITH v AS                                           
(
  SELECT TO_NUMBER(COLUMN_VALUE)a, rownum i            -- Convert the input string into rows 
  FROM   XMLTABLE(('"'||REPLACE(:1,' ','","')||'"'))   -- using space as the separator between elements
)
, c(p,n) AS                        
(
  SELECT a, 2 FROM v WHERE i=1                         -- Initialize the recursive view
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT a*CEIL((p+.1)/a),n+1 FROM c,v WHERE i=n       -- Compute the value for the nth element
)
SELECT p FROM c;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Chez Scheme (140 Bytes)

Golfed Version:

```
(define(f l)(define(g l p m)(cond((null? l)l)((<(*(car l)m)(+ p 1))(g l p(+ m 1)))(else(cons(*(car l)m)(g(cdr l)(* m(car l))1)))))(g l 0 1))
```

Ungolfed Version:

```
(define(f l)
  (define(g l p m)
    (cond
      ((null? l) l)
      ((< (* (car l) m) (+ p 1)) (g l p (+ m 1)))
      (else (cons (* (car l) m) (g (cdr l) (* m (car l)) 1)))
    )
  )
  (g l 0 1)
)
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##jY/BbsIwEETv/YoRl66pKuE4OEaq1B/hghJDkZyAGnGgP5/OGqg41dFK9q73ze54bL9iH995/kyTdHF/HKLskcwjPyDhjN5Iexo6keGS0ifbBORDltLuvlmx/UbKGnPjWfVaGYlpjCodn9mDtJ2mskR/fzVK3@UrldLMcTyn3RW08yobNl/@nhbbYfFUZsKiKjJVNvU/08DN2JWjyK1Rw3LpjJEOGgHWF1EPnesw5zcbkh6qaIJaCaEoCaDIUkHc8Sobsmvk4XWDiqbUnfdocupQUz/9Ag)

Comment: `* m(car l)` can be `*(car l)m`.